# I want to run this on click function on my enter key function

Tags: jquery, onclick, keyup

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $(this).focus();
      valtext = $('li.active').attr('data-upc');
      $('#itemLookup').val(valtext);
     $scope.itemObj.searchStr = valtext
      $('#itemLookup').focus();
      });
  $('#itemLookup').on('keyup', function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13){
       $(this).focus();
      valtext = $('li.active').attr('data-upc');
      $('#itemLookup').val(valtext);
     $scope.itemObj.searchStr = valtext
      $('#itemLookup').focus();
     }
```

});
my enter key code is not working
I can't get the value of valtext inside the enter key function

Comment: And what's your question about this code? Anything not workin so far?

Comment: I am not getting the valtext value in enter key function

Comment: Pleae add all clarification, and your debugging attempts, to the question by editing it